# Why HttpPostedFile is coming null in action method from view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view

I am trying to upload a file but while saving it throws error in action i.e. object reference not set and also the value is NULL.

It's the same class that is getting passed and saved but stil it throws error. Why it's null? It is binded to the same viewmodel.

```
@model VAILCertificates.UI.ViewModels.AddInspectionReportViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "InspectionReport", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
          <div class="col-md-5">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          </div>
     </div>
     <button class="btn btn-success btn-outline btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save" style="font-size:medium"></i>  Add</button>
}
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Create(AddInspectionReportViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase FileName)   
    {
         string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/Certificates/");
                            model.File.SaveAs(FilePath + Path.GetFileName(model.File.FileName));
         model.InspectionReport.FileName = Path.GetFileName(model.File.FileName);

        InspectionReportDAL.AddInspectionReport(model.InspectionReport);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class AddInspectionReportViewModel
{
     public HttpPostedFile File { get; set; }
     public InspectionReport InspectionReport { get; set; }
}
```

Class:

```
public class InspectionReport
    {
        //General Details
        public int InspectionReportID { get; set; }


        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }
```

Update: the internal error is

```
The parameter conversion from type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.
```

Comment: Please check if the html input file element has the "name" attribute matching with your binding server-side c# class. <input type="file" name="File"   />

Comment: @RasikJain: yes it's the same

Answer (score 2):

`HttpPostedFileBase FileName`

`model.File`

The parameter name the method is expecting is FileName.

Edit this `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file" })`

to

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File.FileName , new { @class = "form-control", type = "file" })`

Based on the comments I would do the following if possible.

If I were you I would remove the `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file" })` and replace it with:

`<input type="file" name="FileName" id="fileUpload or whatever" accept="//Whatever file you want to accept">`

At the current state you are never passing anything to the `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter, just the model and so it is always null.

Comment: I did. It doesn't work. Also it should accept the File because we are posting that... not it;s name

Comment: It has turned me insane. this is so simple yet not workin

Comment: @PostingQuestions what I am saying is that the parameter name in the controller function does not match the variable name in the form. Its expecting a `FileName` but nowhere in the form is `FileName` provided. Only a variable called `File` which consists of a variable called `FileName`

Comment: The parameter conversion from type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.

Comment: @PostingQuestions Please see the edit to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Change viewModel to:

```
 public class AddInspectionReportViewModel
            {
                [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
                public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
                public InspectionReport InspectionReport { get; set; }
            }
```

change view to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-outline btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save" style="font-size:medium"></i>  Add</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing HttpPostedFile to HttpPostedFileBase has worked.

```
 public class AddInspectionReportViewModel
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
        public InspectionReport InspectionReport { get; set; }
    }
```